# Python: Getting Keyerror when parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, string, parsing

I have just made a program to parse some data from an api.
The api gives data back with a JSON format. When I try to parse it it gives me a key error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(parsed_json['plain'])
KeyError: 'plain'
```

This is the part of the code that matters (the rest is just for making the url, works perfectly fine)

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url2).read()
strr = str(response)


if "plain" in strr:
    parsed_json = json.loads(response.decode("UTF-8"))
    print(parsed_json['plain'])
elif "INVALID HASH" in strr:
    print("You have entered an invalid hash.")
elif "NOT FOUND" in strr:
    print("The hash is not found")
elif "LIMIT REACHED" in strr:
    print("You have reached the max requests per minute, please try again in one minute.")
```

I am trying to get the data in the plain field.
Here is the output from the API:

```
{
  "REQUEST": "FOUND",
  "739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c": {
    "plain": "test",
    "hexplain": "74657374",
    "algorithm": "MD5X5PLAIN"
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like `"plain"` is a subkey of `"739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c"`.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I am trying to get the "test" after plain. Not plain itself.

Comment: `"test"` is the value of `"plain"` key right?

Comment: @KevinGuan It indeed is, user3554031's answer worked out for me, I just don't understand why I had to use parsed_json['739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c']

Comment: Because `"test"` is a dict **inside** dict `'739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c'`.

Comment: @KevinGuan Aha, now I kinda get it, will continue to look into it, thank you!

Comment: Okay, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to see what is going on when you can see the nested structure of the JSON object you are trying to target data inside of:

**Working Example #1** — Tested with Python **2.6.9** and **2.7.10** and **3.3.5** and **3.5.0**

```
import json

json_string = '''
{
    "REQUEST": "FOUND",
    "739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c": {
        "plain": "test",
        "hexplain": "74657374",
        "algorithm": "MD5X5PLAIN"
    }
}
'''

if 'plain' in json_string:
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
    print(parsed_json['739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c']['plain'])
```

'plain' is a child of '739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c'

**Edit**

The following example loops through parsed_json and checks each key for a length of 32 characters and checks the that the key has a child value of 'plain' inside it.

**Working Example #2** — Tested with Python **2.6.9** and **2.7.10** and **3.3.5** and **3.5.0**

```
import json
import re

def is_MD5(s):
    return True if re.match(r"([a-f\d]{32})", key) else False

strr = '''
{
    "REQUEST": "FOUND",
    "739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c": {
        "plain": "test",
        "hexplain": "74657374",
        "algorithm": "MD5X5PLAIN"
    }
}
'''

parsed_json = json.loads(strr)

for key, value in parsed_json.items():
    if is_MD5(key) and 'plain' in parsed_json[key]:
        xHash = key
        xPlain = parsed_json[key]['plain']

        print('value in key "plain" in key "{0}" is "{1}"'.format(*[xHash,
                                                                    xPlain]))
```

**Output**

```
the value of key "plain" in key "739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c" is "test"
```

Comment: One question if I may ask, what if the 739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c is different? Because the hash will be different all the time, how to make it like dynamic so that it grabs that too?

Comment: @user3104326 see Example #2 for a much more elegant solution to handling a dynamic key.

Comment: @user3104326 Example #2 is now more robust with an MD5 regex match on the key, this is better because it not only checks that the length is 32 but also checks that it only contains characters that are in a valid MD5 hash. Take note that I only allowed for lowercase alphabet characters and digits.

Comment: Ahh I see, well that's a really nice program man, but I found a way to do that hash thing before the plain, because I can just use the hash that I put in :), anyway, would you mind if I send you my finished code so that you can look at it? Also the api that I use allows for almost any hash that isn't salted ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your data, `'plain'` is not a member of `parsed_json`.  It *is* a member of `parsed_json['739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c']`.  So `parsed_json['739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c']['plain']` should work.

JSON is a hierarchical data structure.  The top-level brackets indicate that the whole thing is one object that will get assigned to `parsed_json`.  Each member is a name-value pair; the value of `'REQUEST'` is `'FOUND'`.  The value of `'739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c'`, however, is a sub-object, indicated by the opening bracket.  Its members are `'plain'`, `'hexplain'`, and `'algorithm'`.  This should be more clear if I write it like this:

```
parsed_json: {
    "REQUEST":"FOUND",
    "739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c": {
        "plain":"test",
        "hexplain":"74657374",
        "algorithm":"MD5X5PLAIN"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, That worked and I get test now. Why is it a member of that, is it like a title or something like that (new to programming, never used json)