# Python: How to parse a JSON member name

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have asked a question yesterday, but I wasn't careful and I didn't see one thing, as you can see here [Python: Getting Keyerror when parsing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188546/python-getting-keyerror-when-parsing-json/)
The answer to the question was to use

```
parsed_json['739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c']['plain']
```

Instead of

```
parsed_json['plain']
```

But what I didn't see was that ['739c5b1cd5681e668f689aa66bcc254c'] can also change, now is there a way to parse that too? Sorry if I didn't use the correct name for it, I am not familiar with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value can change, you might want to iterate over the dictionary so then you can index in without knowing the value.

```
for key in parsed_json:
    # do something with the following
    parsed_json[key]['plain']
```

Comment: Wow that's smart! Thank you! I couldn't think of that! Thanks!